# TranslatePoint within a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, coordinates, transform

I have a scroll viewer in my application that contains a canvas, in which I have a tree custom-drawn tree structure. I'm trying to get the position of a particular node element in the canvas relative to the scroll viewer (so I can scroll to it), but my attempts aren't working.

I've tried using `marker.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), scrollViewer)` (where `marker` is the element in the canvas), but this is just returning the position of the canvas, rather than the marker. Similarly, if I try `marker.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), layoutCanvas)`, I invariably just get `(0,0)` as the result, regardless of where the marker actually is.

Here's my code:

```
var marker = m_Metadata[node].Marker;
var location = marker.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), scrollViewer); // This inorrectly gives the position of the canvas, rather than the marker.
var size = new Size(marker.Width, marker.Height);
var markerArea = new Rect(location, size);

double horizontalOffset = (markerArea.Right + markerArea.Left - scrollViewer.ViewportWidth) / 2;
double verticalOffset = (markerArea.Bottom + markerArea.Top - scrollViewer.ViewportHeight) / 2;
```

I've also tried using `marker.TransformToVisual(scrollViewer).Transform(new Point(0, 0)`, but this gives the same results.

I can work around it by using `Canvas.GetLeft`, `Canvas.GetTop` et al, but this is messy and convoluted (since they won't always be left- and top-aligned).

How can I fix this, or does it just not work for canvases?

Comment: Question, doesn't a canvas restrict you to aligning items based on offset from top and left? You can't align on right or bottom in a canvas. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Nope, you can use Canvas.SetBottom and Canvas.SetRight as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a simple workaround method for this problem. It works, but it's not very clean, so if anyone has an answer to this I'd still appreciate it! Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
private static Point GetCanvasChildPosition(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var canvas = element.Parent as Canvas;

    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(element);
    double top = Canvas.GetTop(element);

    bool isLeftAligned = !double.IsNaN(left);
    bool isTopAligned = !double.IsNaN(top);

    double x;
    double y;

    if (isLeftAligned)
    {
        x = left;
    }
    else
    {
        x = canvas.Width - Canvas.GetRight(element) - element.Width;
    }

    if (isTopAligned)
    {
        y = top;
    }
    else
    {
        y = canvas.Height - Canvas.GetBottom(element) - element.Height;
    }

    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(Visual obj)`? I'm not in front of Studio, but I seem to recall using that for just this sort of thing in the past...

Comment: This just gives (0,0) as before, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm...this may sound like a stupid question, but when is the code you wrote being called? User-initiated event handler? On initialization? Construction? etc? The answer I'm groping for here is maybe you're trying to pull details on a UI bit that hasn't actually finished being composited yet...

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get it to scroll to the currently selected node. This will always happen as a result of a user interaction, though, by which point the tree has been correctly rendered.