# How to draw thousands of points on a Canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing

I'm developing a heat-map (or rather heat-scatter-graph tool) tool for a popular game. I'm quite new to WPF, and I'm at the point where I need to draw thousands of points in my Canvas in WPF and trying to find the best approach to do so.

Each point has few properties:
X,Y coordinates and Color in ARGB (alpha based on heat-value, monochrome rather than multi-color).

So far my idea is to have a method which takes in coordinates and A,R,G and B values and adds an ellipse to the children objects of the canvas. It doesn't seem like the most inventive option, so I want to ask if someone knows of a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: depends on business requirements of your program, you might look into *raster image* support inside `WPF`. Where the drawing of the vaste amount of color information is significantly faster, but features, like for example, zooming, might require more work and computational power.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2053288/656243

Comment: Are you opposed to using a library?  There are tons of charting libraries that handle this well without you needing to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: In addition to what Tigran says, you may want to take a look at the WriteableBitmap class, and probably also the WritableBitmapEx library.

Comment: I do have a zoom and pan feature implemented already, which I would rather keep. As for a library, I could definitely take a look, as long as it useful for what I'm trying to achieve (simple blue and red dots with varying alpha). Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx) written by Charles Petzold - where he explains how to use **[The DrawingVisual Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx#id0180138)** to do the same, while ensuring high performance.